# fpga assigning an inout pin to an input pin in verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

I'm trying to connect two pins on an Altera FPGA using the verilog.

Specifically, I'm connecting an `inout` pin to an `input` pin. I get the error.

> The pin "<name>" has multiple drivers

The error is explained on this link.

[Altera description](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd11282006_328.html)

This is the solution:

```
module multi_driver(inout o, input a, b, en);

   // Input a directly drives the bidir pin w/o a tri-state condition
   assign o = a;

   // If en = 1 below, there will be an electrical conflict in the design.
   // To avoid this possibility, the Quartus II software issues an error
   assign o = (en) ? b : 1'bz;

endmodule
```

Could somebody explain what the line `assign o = (en) ? b : 1'bz;` does exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verilog question mark (?) operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336139/verilog-question-mark-operator)

Comment: The code that you mentioned is not a solution, but is an example of incorrect code: "For example, the following design is incorrectly synthesized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assign o = (en) ? b : 1'bz;` is a tri-state latch template for Verilog. When `en` is high `o` port will be output and its value will be `b`. When `en` is low port `o` will be `1'bz` (i.e high impedance state). High impedane state means it will take shape of whatever it is forced from outside the module (i.e it is input).

İf you try to force another signal `assign o = a;` regardless of `en` signal, it will warn you that the signal has multiple drivers. Only when the pin is in high impedance state you can connect a signal from out of the module.